# .net core 2.2 web app : HTTP Error 502.5 ANCM Out-of-process startup failure

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, .net-core-2.2

When i deploy the application from Visual Studio to Azure app service using Framework/Runtime dependent mode, then app service run properly.

But when application is deployed using CICD (using VSTS), then app service fails with above mentioned error in title and following error is logged in stdout log files :

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (App.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter', version: '4.5.0'
    path: 'runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.dll'
```

But the dll is present in mentioned path under .netcoreapp2.0.

I am publishing the application using VSTS agent.

> If i restart the app service then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those errors that can come up for a thousand unrelated reasons.  -Everytime- I get this error it's because I've upgraded Nuget packages in my project and one of those packages uses a version of the .Net Core SDK I haven't installed locally.  I suspect since you're using the Framework dependent mode it could be an issue if it sandboxes you away from other SDK's (not sure if it does, just thinking out loud).

- Make sure your .Net Core SDK's are up to date.
- Try publishing it and sending the whole framework with it if you're using .Net Core as the backend (and not the old framework).
- Check your NuGet's and make sure they're all supported on the framework you're specifying.  I've seen cases where a 4.5 framework assembly 'might' work locally but then error out on the server.  If one of them targets an SDK that isn't on the server you'll get this.

  https://www.blakepell.com/asp-net-core-http-error-502-5-ancm-out-of-process-startup-failure

Answer (score 0):

Since it works fine when you restart the app service, you could add a `Azure App Service manage` task to restart Azure App Service in your pipeline:

```
steps:
- task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
  displayName: 'Restart Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: azureSubscriptionName
    Action: 'Restart Azure App Service'
    WebAppName: AppServiceName
```

Comment: Could you share your pipeline? If you deploy from command line locally, how's the result?

Comment: if i deploy using Visual studio, it works, but after release through pipeline App service doesn't run at all. No errors are getting logged in stdout.

Comment: Could you share your pipeline? How about stopping your app or enabling offline mode for your app during deployment?

Comment: sure i will share

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the first time you try to run, your application can not find this .dll that is required on the server. What you can do is to add this in your .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>               
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Adding the above snippet will export all DLLs needed to run the application (assuming SDK is not available, and runtime is quite lightweight to contain non essential libraries).

Comment: Tried this but got error : Invalid runtimeconfig.json

Comment: Ok lets follow a different approach then. You said that when you deploy from VS using Framework/Runtime dependent mode, application works fine. Lets do the same from devops. When you publish in your pipeline pass the following parameters ´dotnet publish -r <RID> --self-contained false´ this will replicate exactly what you do at VS locally. For dotnet publish documentation look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/